# Problem facing to run ruport from other machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services and set mode remotely. All is going fine and reports running on my machine. I am not using report viewer control, but switch to browser.

Problem is that when I access the report from any other system in browser by providing required url. I m getting the following premission error:

> *Server Error in /ReportServer Application. Access is denied:
>   Description: An error is occured while
>   accessing the resources required to
>   serve for this request. You might have
>   not premission to view the requested
>   resources. Error message: 401.3 : You
>   dont have the premission to view this
>   directory or page using the
>   creditinals you supplied.*

I have go through all step of this article "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365170.aspx" and set remotly premession but after all changes no success and getting same error.

Please some one can tell me or provide step list, that how can I set the premession? that the report can run from other machine. Quick and detail response will

Comment: let me get this straight: You get this error when you use Internet Explorer to access the report server on a machine that is not yours?

Comment: Yes, that not my machine IE, that is on other machine. And reports (report server)are on my machine. I want to access from other PC IE

Answer (score 0):

This link should give you some more steps to follow to set up the permissions as this sounds like a permissions error.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337491.aspx

Also .... does it prompt for a username and password when you visit the site from another machine? if not you may need to add the required authentication methods into IIS (just an idea)

Then create a local (or domain) account for people to use to browse reports and use the properties tab on the report server home page to add them as 'Browser' type members.

When you visit the reports site from another PC it should prompt for sign in details (may not on a domain - not sure), if it errors before showing the home page then it is a security config issue, once you get in you may have a bit more tinkering to do to get the reports to run, but you tend to get slightly more verbose descriptions then so its not too hard to figure out and it normally database security permissions related.

Best of luck.

CB